# how to make text scroll ( like text to slide by clicking prev n next icon) through javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kivRa.jpg)

HOw to make text moving by clicking previous icon and next icon?like image slider...i want only 10 text to visible..rest all r to hide...nd by clicking all should appear.... i dont know javascript please help me!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.new_line {
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    }

.new_line ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 22px ;
    }

.new_line ul li img {
    float:left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="new_line">
  <ul>
  <li> <img src="next.png"/> </li>
    <!--<li> <a href="#"> text 1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 2</a></li>-->
    <li> <a href="#"> text 3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 4</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 5</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 6</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 7</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 8</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 9</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 10</a></li>
    <!--<li> <a href="#"> text 11</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> text 12</a></li>-->
    <li> <img src="prev.png"/> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a better pagination.

Comment: I you are using bootstrap you can do this with the carousel.

Comment: Yea carousel will help you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp see this will help you.Also see http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: this might be help http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/dopudeduto/edit?html,css,js,output

- I included the bootstrap pagination, which was recommended in your
  comments.
- You can change to amount of li's that is displayed modifying the
  limit variable.
- in the beginning all li's but the first 3 are hidden using a data-attribute (they are hidden using css)
- afterwards the event listener are bound to the buttons
- in the functions for prev it first checks whether the first li is already shown

  - if not the last element is hidden
  - and the element before the currently first one is displayed

Let me know if you have any problems with this solution.

Comment: I actually want to put this in my project..but m not able to do this...dont know the reason

Comment: You need to include bootstrap in your project. 
Copy the HTML, CSS and JS into the specific files or include it in the html.
You can download a version using the file > download dialog.

Let me know if you have trouble.